# How to use S3DistCp in java code

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I want to copy output of job from EMR cluster to Amazon S3 pro-grammatically.

How to use `S3DistCp` in java code to do the same.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. I think this question may be a little broad for this part of SO. Consider amending, or posting instead to one of the discussion areas.

Answer (score 3):

#### hadoop `ToolRunner` can run this.. since `S3DistCP extends Tool`

Below is the usage example:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import com.amazon.external.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.S3DistCp

public class CustomS3DistCP{
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomS3DistCP.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     log.info("Running with args: " + args);

     System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new S3DistCp(), args));
   }
```

*you have to have s3distcp jar in your classpath
You can call this program from a shell script.*

Hope that helps!

Comment: I understand that this is bit late answer! but some how it addresses the approach. thats why thought of putting here. @user2664210 please ack.